# React Array spread some common data for all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am learning React and came across a slightly tricky problem for my level. From my API call I get a response which is an array of objects. I want to submit data add some object data . To get the idea of how the response looks, this is an example (it is array of JSON) some data want to spread in array object data {school:"test",schoolId:"2"}

```
Response

data = [
  {0: {name: "tom"}},
  {1: {name: "Pope"}},
  {2: {name: "jack"}}
 ];


Response to want send like
data = [
   {
name: "tom",
school :"testing",
schoolId:"2"
},
   {
name: "Pope",
school :"testing",
schoolId:"2"},
   {
name: "jack",
school :"testing",
schoolId:"2"}
 ];
```

Comment: Just use `.map` on your data.. `data.map(item => ({...wrapper, item}))` where `wrapper = { school: 'testing'. schoolOd: 2}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.map` on your original array..

Define your object which you want to merge (eg: wrapper) and so a simple spread on it inside `.map`

```
const data = [
  {name: "tom"},
  {name: "Pope"},
  {name: "jack"}
];

const wrapper = {
  school: 'testing',
  schoolId: 2
};

const result = data.map(item => ({...wrapper, ...item}));

console.log(result);

/*
[
  { school: 'testing', schoolId: 2, name: 'tom' },
  { school: 'testing', schoolId: 2, name: 'Pope' },
  { school: 'testing', schoolId: 2, name: 'jack' }
]
*/
```

[Live version](https://replit.com/@adityaparab/UnusualSatisfiedRoot#index.js)